# Can I add at the same layer customised filters with random ones in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

What I mean is namely is that in addition to something like:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, 3)
```

You can have constant filters such as `filter_vals = np.array([[-1, -1, 1], [-1, -1, 1], [-1, -1, 1]])`

at the same layer.

Comment: The conv layer you defined has 10 filters shaped 3x3 but the kernel you defined is 4x4... Did you mean to replace one of the kernels with a fixed 3x3 kernel?

Comment: This was just an illustration, the dimension matter very little. I will fix this

Comment: Well, it does if you want to replace the weights of `conv1`? Do you want to also change the size of the kernel of `conv1`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you want random parameters be learnable (requires_grad), while fixed are not. I don't think it should be done in one `conv`, rather with two, followed by concatenation, such as:

```
conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 3)
conv2 = nn.Conv2d(1, 4, 3)
conv2.weight = ...

y1 = conv1(x)
with torch.no_grad():    
    y2 = conv2(x)
y = torch.cat( (y1,y2), dim=3 )
```

Comment: This exactly the point I want to avoid. since the initial weighting of the matrix i.e Conv2d.weight has heavy impact on the network, and by adding these hard filters we may avoid these biases

Comment: May be you want to fix random seed? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you are looking for is to replace the weights of the convolution layer by the weights defined in `filter_vals`, you can first expand it to the number of filters, here `10`, then replace the weights of `conv1`:

```
>>> conv1.weight.data = torch.from_numpy(filter_vals).expand_as(conv1.weight)
```